# C#, create excel 97-2003 (.xls) Interop

Tags: c#, excel, interop

using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

I need to save a excel file (.xls) from my datagridview. All works fine, writing data, changing cell format etc. But problem appears while saving the doc.

```
string format = "yyyy_MM_dd_HH-mm";
string pathtoexport = @"C:\DM\SMS\Przychodzace\Znalezione_SMS_" + DateTime.Now.ToString(format) + ".xls";
oWB.SaveAs(pathtoexport, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, missing, missing,
      false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
      missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
    }
```

Well some days ago it was working, but now it can only say

HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"}

I need .xls to import it to SQL. Any advices?

---

Before the problem was at Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, when Iv changed it to Normal it was doing well. Now it doesnt work. LOst much time to handle it on my own with google, but I failed.

```
oWB.SaveAs(MyFile + @"C:\SMS\XMLCopy.xls",
      Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, missing, missing,
      false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
      missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 string format = "yyyy_MM_dd_HH-mm";
        string pathtoexport = "C:\\DM\\SMS\\Przychodzace\\Znalezione_SMS_" + DateTime.Now.ToString(format) + ".xls";

        oWB.SaveAs(pathtoexport, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Now it works. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

Try with `Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault`

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like an Interop version conflict. Are you experiencing the problem on the same machine as it used to work on or have you moved to another? If you're on the same try to back track and figure out any changes or updates. If you're on another then verify that you have the correct version installed there.

This might sound stupid but I've encountered all sorts of wierdness when moving from dev -> test -> prod due to inconsistencies between the environments.

If you haven't already, try removing the reference from the project and reapplying it.

It could also be due to permissions (or lack there of). Have you tried creating a plain text file from the same piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything obviously wrong with your code. Is it possible that there is some problem with accessing that path? If you try to save a file manually to that exact path (assuming that you're logged in under the same account as the interop process runs under), does it work?

Otherwise, are you using some kind of Excel template file or something that could have become corrupted?

Answer (score 0):

If you/your customer can afford, there is [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx) which is great for generating Excel documents from scratch, *without* the need for Office being installed on a machine.

On the other hand, the solution costs money.

Comment: I need free solution bcz we will use it only at one module. So its not the anwser :(